# Error when sending an email: Error Cannot POST /assets/php/form.php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a problem with sending an email.
I get this error

`<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Error</title> </head> <body> <pre>Cannot POST /assets/php/form.php</pre> </body> </html>`

The structure of my files looks like this
dist
-asstes
--php
---form.php
index.html

In the form I have given such a path `<form class="fs-13 text-uppercase" id="form" method="POST" action="assets/php/form.php">`

I use the server gulp connect php and this is my taks in gulp file

```
// Configure the browserSync task
gulp.task('browserSync', () => {
  $.connectPhp.server({}, () => {
    browserSync.init({
      server: {
        baseDir: PATHS.dist,
        proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000',
      }
    });
  });
});


// Dev task
gulp.task('dev', ['browserSync', 'vendor', 'assets', 'html', 'sass', 
  gulp.watch(PATHS.src + '/assets/php/*.php', ['php', browserSync.reload]);
});
```

This is my js file

```
  $('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        formMessages.text(response);
        $('input[name=name]').val('');
        $('input[name=email]').val('');

      }).fail(function(data) {
          if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $('.form-status').text(data.responseText);
          } else {
            $('.form-status').text('ERROR');
          }
      });
    });
```

and php

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


    if (empty($name) OR empty($email)) {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
      exit;
    }

    $recipient = "email@gamil.com";
    $subject = "Email";
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
    $eamil_headers = "From: $name";


    if (mail_utf8($recipient, $name, $subject, $email, $email_content, $eamil_headers)) {
      http_response_code(200);
      echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
      http_response_code(500);
      echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
  } else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
  }

  function mail_utf8($recipient, $name, $subject = '(No subject)', $email, $message = '' ) {
    $name = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($name)."?=";
    $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
                "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    return mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
?>
```

from

```
 <form id="form" method="POST" action="assets/php/form.php">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="first-name" class="form-control text-white" type="text" name="name">
                      <label for="first-name">your name?*</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="email" class="form-control text-white" type="email" name="email">
                      <label for="email">Your email?*</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-none float-md-right">Let's work together</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

I do not know where the problem lies and why it is not sending mail

Comment: Check the browser console to see what you are sending. Check the web server log to see any errors.

Comment: @JasonK In console is one error - jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/assets/php/form.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It cant find the page. Check where the file actually is.

Comment: @JasonK 
I checked, the js file is well connected, and php, it seems that it is ok, the path is good

Comment: If the path to form.php was good you would not get a 404 error. That error is generated by the web server.

Comment: @JasonK In form I have path: assets/php/form.php and my file structure is this same. I have folder dist 
and in this folder I have an html file and assets folder

Comment: is your web server also running on "127.0.0.1:8000"? Where's the HTML code for your form?

Comment: @Jaxi I added my html code

Comment: EDIT: change your form url to 127.0.0.1:8000/assets/php/form.php

Comment: @Jaxi I do not understand the question. locally, my address is http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @Doe check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and your server are on different ports.

You have

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="assets/php/form.php">
```

which will go to `http://localhost:3000/assets/php/form.php`.

Change this action to:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/assets/php/form.php">
```

which by the looks of it is your gulp server address.

When you deploy however, you will have to take it into account that it would be this.

Comment: I get this error jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/assets/php/form.php 404 (Not Found) 
Still the same :(

Comment: try `localhost:8000/form.php`, it seems that /assets/php/ might be your base path

Comment: This will be your issue, but I haven't a clue where your PHP runs because I don't know where `PATHS.dist` is.